# How to solve the diffusion equation in a ball using fourier series

Tags: partial-differential-equations, fourier-analysis, heat-equation

This is quite a simple question, but it's been about 7 years since I've solved something like this, so need a little bit of help to refresh me!

**Problem**

Suppose we have a ball, radius $r_0$, with the diffusion equation
$$\frac{\partial c(r,t)}{\partial t} = 
D\nabla^2
c(r,t),
\quad r\in[0,r_0],t\geq 0$$

with robin boundary conditions
$$
-D\frac{\partial c}{\partial r} = pc
,\quad \text{on}\ \ r=r_0
$$

with initial conditions
$$c(r,0)=c_0\qquad \forall r\in[0,r_0]$$

**How far I have got**

If we let
$$c = R(r)T(t)$$

then we find 
$T(t)=\exp(-D \lambda^2 t)$ and

$$r^2R''+2rR'+\lambda^2r^2R=0$$

Letting $Q(r):=r\>R(r)$ we find

$$r(Q''+\lambda^2 Q)=r^2R''+2rR'+\lambda^2 r^2R=0$$

Which upon solving and back substitution we find

$$R(r)={1\over r}\sin(\lambda r)$$

BC imply that
$$\tan r_0\lambda={D\over D-r_0p}r_0\lambda$$

Which has infinite +ve solutions, giving us

$$c(r,t) = \sum_{n=1}^{\infty}{A_n\over r}\sin(\lambda r)\exp(-D \lambda^2 t)$$

As $\lambda_0=0$. Therefore
$$c_0 = \sum_{n=1}^{\infty}{A_n\over r}\sin(\lambda r),\qquad \forall r\in[0,r_0]$$

**Question**

I know I'm being dense here, but could someone explain how to find $A_n$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I wouldn't call it a "quite simple" question.

Generally, the coefficients $A_n$ are found by expanding the initial condition ($c_0$ here) in the basis formed by the eigenfunctions (here $R_n(r) = \frac{1}{r}\sin (\lambda_nr)$). The eigenfunctions are orthogonal for any symmetric differential operator $L$, that is $\langle Lf, g\rangle = \langle f, Lg\rangle$ for all functions $f,g$ that satisfy the boundary conditions. The inner product $\langle \cdot, \cdot\rangle$ here is an integral, possibly with a weight. When the eigenfunctions are orthogonal, their coefficients are 
$$
A_n = \frac{\langle c_0, R_n\rangle }{\langle R_n, R_n\rangle }
$$

In this case, I somehow fail to see $Lf=r^2f''+2rf'+\lambda^2 r^2 f$ as symmetric even with a weight; but even if it is and the eigenfunctions are orthogonal with some weight,  the explicit computation of coefficients
is hopeless because $\lambda_n$ are not known explicitly.

Comment: For certain values of $D$ and $p$, $\lambda_n$ can be approximated, something I'm working on. Thank you for your answer! Contains a lot I should read up on.

Comment: The book on Partial Differential Equations by Strauss covers separation of variables carefully, including Robin boundary conditions (which, btw, is what you have here; not Neumann's)

Comment: Thanks! And yes, one of my colleagues just pointed that out to me also!